# Can these conditions imply that this bivariate function converges to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Assume that $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are smooth functions defined on $[a,b]\times[0,+\infty)$. And $g(x,y)$ is a positive function.

We already have：

- $\int_a^b(fg)^2dx \rightarrow 0$ as $y\rightarrow +\infty$.
- $\int_a^b(g)^2dx \rightarrow C$ as $y\rightarrow +\infty$.
- $\int_a^b(g)^2dx$ is monotone increasing and bounded.
- $\int_a^b(g)^2dx\equiv C$ if and only if $(f)^2\equiv0$.

Where $C$ is a given positive constant.

Can the above conditions imply that $(f)^2\rightarrow 0$ as $y\rightarrow +\infty$ for all $x\in[a,b]$?

I have been puzzled by this problem for many days. I kindly request everyone's help, and I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Is the fourth statement correct? There is no $f$ in the integral.

Comment: Considering the first three statements, the answer is no, because you can take $f$ and $g$ such that $\mathrm{supp}(f) \cap \mathrm{supp}(g) = \emptyset$ when $y\to\infty$, where $\mathrm{supp}$ is the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of the function.

Comment: In fact, the above problem is a simplified description of a problem I am currently working on. Due to my weak analytical skills and the lack of people around me to discuss with, I came to the forum to seek help from everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Consider the following counterexample on $[a,b] = [-1,1]$.

$$\begin{aligned}
g(x,y) &= \begin{cases} \sqrt{\left(2-\frac{1}{y+1}\right) \frac{3}{I} e^{-1/x^2} + \frac{1}{y+1}}& \text{ if } x > 0\\
                  \sqrt{\frac{1}{y+1}}& \text{ if } x\leq 0
\end{cases} \\
f(x,y) &= g(-x, y),
\end{aligned}
$$
where  $I := \int_{0}^1 e^{-1/x^2}dx$. Note $g$ is smooth as it is a composition of smooth functions ($g$ is never $0$, so no issue with the $\sqrt{}$).

Then for $y \in [0, \infty)$
$$\begin{aligned}
\require{cancel}
\int_{-1}^1 g(x,y)^2 dx &=\frac{3}{\cancel{I}} \left(2-\frac{1}{y+1}\right) \cancel{\int_{0}^1 e^{-1/x^2} dx} + \frac{1}{y+1} \cancelto{2}{\int_{-1}^1 dx} \\
&= 6 - \frac{3}{y+1} + \frac{2}{y+1} \\
&= 6 - \frac{1}{y+1}.
\end{aligned}
$$
This is an increasing bounded function in $y$, so condition $(3)$ is satisfied. For condition $(2)$, we see our $C$ will be $6$. Furthermore, $\int_{-1}^1 g(x,y)^2 dx \neq C$ for any $y \in [0, \infty)$ and $f(x,y)^2 > 0$ for all $(x,y) \in [-1, 1] \times [0, \infty)$, so condition (4) is satisfied. To see that condition (1) is satisfied, observe
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-1}^1 f(x,y)^2g(x,y)^2 dx &= 2 \int_{0}^1  \frac{1}{y+1} \left( \left(2-\frac{1}{y+1}\right) \frac{3}{I} e^{-1/x^2} + \frac{1}{y+1} \right)dx \\
&= \frac{2}{y+1}\left(2-\frac{1}{y+1}\right)\frac{3}{\cancel{I}}  \cancel{\int_{0}^1 e^{-1/x^2} dx} + \frac{2}{(y+1)^2} \cancelto{1}{\int_0^1 dx} \\
&= \frac{12}{y+1} - \frac{\cancelto{4}{6}}{(y+1)^2} + \cancel{\frac{2}{(y+1)^2}} \\
&\to 0 \text{ as } y \to \infty
\end{aligned}
$$

However,
$$f(-1,y) \to \sqrt{\frac{6}{I} e^{-1}}$$
as $y\to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for providing a brilliantly crafted counterexample! However, I apologize for not fully clarifying the problem at that time. In fact, function $g$ should be a positive function, and $C$ is a positive constant. I am very sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: @Serge I have modified the counterexample to address your comment.

Comment: A brilliant counterexample! Thank you very much for answering my question.